# fmt:message with properties.get not returning proper message

Tags: jsp, aem

In AEM 6.2, I'm trying to get an i18n message with embedded html code to be processed properly on the page. There is a granite node labelled "i18nLabel". When I use fmt:message in the following way:

```
<fmt:message key="${properties.i18nLabel}"/>
```

It prints ???I18NMESSAGE01??? on the page.

What is going on? Shouldn't it format the I18NMESSAGE01 key into it's text value?

I've tried using the following code structure and it works to print the correct message on the page, but it is also printing the html tags instead of processing them properly in the way that writing  does.

```
<%@ page import="com.day.cq.i18n.I18n" %>
<% I18n i18n = new I18n(slingRequest); %>
<%
String i18nKey = properties.get("gl_label_i18nLabel", String.class);
String i18nMessage = i18n.get(i18nKey);
%><p><%= i18nMessage %></p><%
%>
```

The i18n message is:

If you are having trouble viewing the PDFs, you can <a href="https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/otherversions/">download Adobe Reader</a> from Adobe free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <%@ page import="java.util.*,com.day.cq.i18n.I18n" %>
<c:set var="htmlMessage" value="${property:singleValue(resource,'i18nMessage', '')}"/>
<c:if test="${empty htmlMessage}">
<c:set var="htmlMessage"><fmt:message key="properties.i18nLabel"/></c:set>
</c:if>
```

Comment: If I try to use this in my code: <c:set var="htmlMessage" value="${property:singleValue(resource,'i18nMessage', '')}"/> I get the following error: Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/dash/components/global/glb-label/glb-label.jsp(45,26) The attribute prefix property does not correspond to any imported tag library